# Understanding Manipulating Inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Today I came across the following inequality in class:$$24-4k<0$$
I tried to manipulate it like this:
$$24-(24-4k)<24-0$$
$$4k<24$$
$$k<6$$
This is obviously incorrect. However I can't seem to understand what the problem is.
When solving algebraic equations we can use the method above:
$$24-4k=0$$
$$24-(24-4k)=24-0$$
$$4k=24$$
$$k=6$$
So why doesn't it work for manipulating Inequalities.
Furthermore, why doesn't the following work?
Eg.
$$24-24-4k<24-0$$
$$-4k<24$$
$$k>-6$$
Please could someone help me. I'm very confused.

Comment: The very first step is wrong. Look: for equations, you can go from $x=y$ to $-x=-y$. For inequalities, you *can't* go from $-2<7$ to $2<-7$. But that's what you did.

Comment: See if you can follow this hint: Solve it like an ordinary equation, but remember that your unknown variable should be on the left side and must be positive. Multiplying the inequality with a negative sign flips the inequality sign.

Comment: Adding $24$ to $24-4k$ does not equal $24-(24-4k)$

Comment: What's wrong with the last manipulation?

Comment: The last set of formulas doesn't even work for equations, since $24-(24-k)$ isn't the same thing as $24-24-k$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have: $24 - 4k < 0$, and immediately under it: $24 - (24 - 4k) < 24 - 0$.

That's the same as ADDING $-(24 - 4k)$.  But multiplying an inequality by a negative number REVERSES the inequality.  For example, $4 < 5$ but $-4 > -5$.

From $24 - 4k < 0$,
$$-(24 - 4k) > 0$$
$$24 - (24 - 4k) > 24 - 0$$
$$4k > 24$$
$$k > 6$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer makes lots of sense. However what's the wrong with my last manipulation?

Comment: @HaowenXie What are you doing to each side of the equation in the last of the manipulation?